# Document displays nothing when component is exported

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I began learning React a few days ago and attempted to display some simple text. The goal is to have component `button` use its data from `Hello` to spit out the text `hello world`. However, nothing at all is displayed.

This React project was created using `create-react-app`

App.js file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class text extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <Hello />
      </div>
      );
  }
}

class Hello extends Component {
  render(){
    const but = <h1>hello world</h1>;

    return(
        <h1>{this.props.but}</h1>
      );
  }
}

export default text;
```

index.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

I expect that the `<Hello />` tag in the `text` component would transfer the data of component `Hello` via `this.props`, but clearly I am incorrect. A detailed response would be very highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here lies within the fact that you don't really understand how props work in React (but that's ok!)

Props in a general sense is what you pass from a `parent` component to a `child` component

Suppose you have a node graph like the following:

```
Text
  |
   - Hello
```

Where `Hello` is a child of `Text` (as it is in your example), the `Hello`'s props would be passed from `Text`, its parent component.

So in your case, if you want to use props, you would need to change this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class text extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <Hello but="Hello World"/>
      </div>
      );
  }
}

class Hello extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
        <h1>{this.props.but}</h1>
      );
  }
}

export default text;
```

Another way is to change the component to this:

```
class Hello extends Component {
  render(){
    const but = "Hello world";
    return(
        <h1>{but}</h1>
      );
  }
}
```

This way, you don't need to use props at all.

### Why use props?

Props is a nice way of being able to update your components' data.

Suppose you have a component that is currently displaying "Hello World". How would you tell it to change the text to "Goodbye World"?

Through props, anytime a property (props is short for properties) is updated, the component automagically reloads and renders again, always rendering with the newest property. You can use this to update what is rendered.

### When do I not use props?

Almost never. Most of the time, you want to pass in properties with props (Unless that particular property will never change). This is to make sure that all of your components will be reusable.

Answer (score 0):

`props` are things that get passed to children in React. In your Hello component, you're passing `this.props.but`, but `but` is not passed into the component. `this.props.but` is `undefined`.

If you have `but` locally defined, you just pass that variable:

```
return(
    <h1>{but}</h1>
);
```

or, if you did want to use `this.props.but`, you would utilize props by passing in `but` in the `text` component.

```
<div>
    <Hello but={'helloooo'} />
</div>
```